# <tr1/random> not found while compiling OpenCV

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile OpenCV for iOS following these [instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html).

I have installed lastest iOS SDK, and CMake version 2.8.10.2.

I've need the symbolic link but I get this error:

```
In file included from /Users/xxx/SourceCode/OpenCV/opencv/modules/softcascade/src/integral_channel_builder.cpp:43:
In file included from /Users/xxx/SourceCode/OpenCV/opencv/modules/softcascade/src/precomp.hpp:56:
/Users/xxx/SourceCode/OpenCV/opencv/modules/softcascade/src/_random.hpp:75:12: fatal error: 'tr1/random' file not found
#  include <tr1/random>
           ^
```

I have checked if the file is in my laptop, `find /Developer/ -name random` and this is what I get:

```
XXXX-MacBook-Pro:/ xxx$ find /Developer/ -name random
/Developer//Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/random
/Developer//Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/numpy/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/numpy/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/numpy/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/random
/Developer//Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/random
/Developer//Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/random
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: tr1 is part of C++, are you compiling for Objective-C++?

Comment: I don't know, I'm following their instructions: `python opencv/ios/build_framework.py ios`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have  this compile error too.
I change the file "ios/cmake/Modules/Platform/iOS.cmake" 
line 43

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")

to

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libstdc++ -headerpad_max_install_names -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden")

and success build opencv.framework... Hope this will help ..